# Powershell input checking

Tags: powershell

1. I would like to check the input option is allow 1-3 number ONLY, and input other numbers and characters will show the warning message, how to do that?
2. Can I check the input user account [value] from AD user is whether exist or not on Powershell? If the record not exist, just return the warning message.

Please help. Thanks!

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
import-module C:\PS\color_menu.psm1


CreateMenu -Title "AD User Account Expire Tools" -MenuItems "View the User Account Expire Date","Set the User Account Expire Date","Exit" -TitleColor Red -LineColor Cyan -menuItemColor Yellow

do {
  [int]$userMenuChoice = 0
  while ( $userMenuChoice -lt 1 -or $userMenuChoice -gt 3) {
    Write-Host "1. View the User Account Expire Date"
    Write-Host "2. Set the User Account Expire Date"
    Write-Host "3. Exit"


    [int]$userMenuChoice = Read-Host "Please choose an option"

    switch ($userMenuChoice) {

      1{$useraccount = Read-Host -prompt "Please input an user account"
        Get-ADUser -Identity $useraccount -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Name, AccountExpirationDate
        Write-Host "";
        Write-Host "";
        }

      2{$useraccount = Read-Host -prompt "Please input an user account"
          do {
          $expiredatetimeStr = Read-Host -prompt "Please input the user expiration date and time (DateFormat: MM/dd/yyyy) or just press Enter to make the account non-expiring"

          if ($expiredatetime = $expiredatetimeStr -as [datetime]) {
            Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $useraccount -DateTime $expiredatetime
            Get-ADUser -Identity $useraccount -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Name, AccountExpirationDate
            Write-Host "";
            Write-Host "";
          } 
          elseif ($expiredatetimeStr.Trim() -eq '') {
            Clear-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $useraccount
            Get-ADUser -Identity $useraccount -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Name, AccountExpirationDate
            Write-Host "";
            Write-Host "";
          }
          else { 
            Write-Warning 'Please enter a valid date.'
            continue
          }
          break
        } while ($true)
        }
      3{Write-Host "Exit";Exit
       }
      default {Write-Host "Incorrect input" -ForegroundColor Red
      Write-Host "";
      Write-Host "";

      }
    }
  }
} while ( $userMenuChoice -ne 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are directly casting a user input to an int:

```
$a = [int] Read-Host
```

What if the return value of `Read-Host` isn't an int?

The solution is to just accept whatever `Read-Host` gives you, and check the value after, e.g:

```
$a = Read-Host
try {
    $intVal = [Convert]::ToInt32($a, 10)
    ... etc ...
}
catch {
    ... etc ...
}
```